# Excel Ranges vs. Arrays

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array, range

I'm having an issue where Excel seems to handle ranges and arrays differently. Please see the example below.

[image: Excel Range vs. Array in Functions]

Why would Excel handle the Array `{"Andy", "Dave", "Sally"}` in a different fashion to Range `B1:B3`?

Is it possible to convert a Range to an Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that using the formula with the array forces Excel to use [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

To have the same functionality with the range, enter that formula as an array formula too, so after typing it press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER